# [android]How to add new column to DB on missing one?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I wrote an application in android that using DB.
In the next version I want to add new column to the DB but without re-installing the application. How can I upgrade the table on missing column exception?

Comment: What do you means by without re-installing? Do you means that you don't want to lose your data stored in db when updating?

Comment: If you are using `SQLiteOpenHelper` just update the DB version number and add the code to modify your DB in `onUpgrade(...)`.

Comment: The method you are looking for is `onUpgrade` in `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: yes, I don't want to loose my data
OK thanks I will look more info on Google
Write in in answer and not comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can simply do it by changing(increment) database version**

```
public class Databas extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if(oldVersion <= DATABASE_VERSION)
        db.execSQL("//write table altering query here ");
    onCreate(db);


}
```

increment database version value with 1 from your current database version value

Comment: why do I need to call onCreate after the alter?

I think it should be oldVersion < newVersion

Comment: because onUpgrade is called only when the database vesion is changed. Likewise onCreate is called only when the table is created. Here the the database version is changed because of altering the table.That's why called onCreate in order to update the table

Comment: why won't you change "oldVersion<=1" to "oldVersion < newVersion" or "oldVersion < DATABASE_VERSION"?

Comment: oldVersion< newVersion is correct. I just assume the current database version value as 1.that's why explicitly used 1 instead of variable.

Comment: The only place where I use the db version is in the constructor and the if statement in upgrade function, I can't understand where does the database version get chagned to 2?

Comment: Database version is intially declared as 2. When the constructor function is executed your database is changed with the new verion value by this statement :  **Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
} **. When this change occurs onUpgrade() method is called as i early mentioned. Then table alteration is done through onCreate() method

Comment: we write Database class as a separate class file and we just create the object of this class in the activity where we need to access the database.So whenever we move to these activites ,object of Database class can be created and constructor is called.So when a change in database version occurs it will be notified and further procedure starts.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by using SQLiteOpenHelper. Let say your current database version is 1. You just change it to 2. Then if there is any version 1 database will be automatically update to version 2 and onUpgrade method will be invoked.

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion <= 1)
            db.execSQL("Do you table alter here ");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where will be the column add?
If I call on create after the alter I won't loose my data?

Comment: onCreate will be called but there is not drop table command in it, so you data will not losing. And column will be added at onUpgrade.

Comment: I meant where in the table it will be added (position). nvm, I found that it adds it to the end.
In onCreate I have Create queries, is it ok? it won't delete my data?

Comment: Oh... sorry, I saw it as when. If you worry about data, why don't you create a dummy project and test on it? It will be safer.

Comment: @AlexKapustian : The order of columns in a DB table doesn't matter any more than the order of rows - that's how SQL DBs work. When you do a query you can re-arrange everything any way you like.